# can i transfer my ps3 copy of grand theft auto V to ps4

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

so I have grand theft auto 5 for ps3 but I want  play it on ps4 so how can like I get it on my ps4 like I don't wont  buy another one so what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no current way of running/transferring your PS3 copy of GTA V on PS4.

Comment: You stated that you don't want to buy another one, did you try trading it in places like gamestop? They probably have copy of PS4 GTA V, and will probably allow you to trade your current PS3 copy with that for a lower price (for ex. if it is $50, you **might** be able to get it for 30$ etc.)

Answer (score -2):

You need to link your social club for gta to your Playstation  network  account then login to your ps4 with that about the then gotto gta on the ps4 settings look for social club settings and login go online and transfer character but do story mode try moving your ps3 memory to your ps 4 using  a flash drive  or external  harddrive

Comment: This doesn't provide an answer to the question. The question asks about the game, not the online characters.

Comment: Your answering for character saves, but OP is asking about the game, itself.